# how to add dynamic JavaScript to dynamically generated Html elements?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an HTML page that gathers data from a database and uses that data to produce dynamic HTML elements. The problem is that these elements have to create a button that submits data without refreshing the page and then call a function `productList(formId);`.

This is the current function:

```js
function getWidgets(){
    
    var listUrl = base_url + widgetsPath + url_auth;
    
    console.log("Sending GET to " + listUrl);
    
    function getSuccess(obj){
        var dataWidget = obj.data;

        for (let i=0; i< dataWidget.length; i++){

            var id = dataWidget[i].id;
            var description = dataWidget[i].description;
            var price = dataWidget[i].pence_price;
            var url = dataWidget[i].url;
            var index = i;
            
            
            console.log("index: ",i);
            console.log(dataWidget[i].id);
            console.log(dataWidget[i].description);
            console.log(dataWidget[i].pence_price);
            console.log(dataWidget[i].url);
            console.log(" ");

            var template =`<!-- product -->
            <div class="container" class="product" id="productId_${index}">
                <form action="" class="product">
                    <img src="${url}"></img>
                    <p class="product_Description">${description}</p>
                    <input type="hidden" class="productId" value=${id}>
                    <input type="hidden" class="price" value="0.${price}">
                    <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
                    <input type="number" class="quantity" value="1" min="1">
                    <button class="submit">Add to cart</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <script>
                        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() =>{
                            const product${index} = document.querySelector("#productId_${index}")
                            product1.addEventListener("submit",e=>{
                                e.preventDefault();
                                var formId = "productId_${index}";
                                productList(formId);
                            });
                        });
            </script>
            <!-- END product -->`

            $("#widgetContainer").append(template);

        }
        console.log("success");
        console.log(dataWidget);
        
    };
    
    $.ajax(listUrl, {type: "GET", data: {},success: getSuccess });
};

getWidgets();
```

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this code? Anything not workig as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to dynamically add a `<script>` block for each widget you append to your page. Instead, you can add a single `submit` event handler that  will be able to handle the `submit` event for *all* of the `<form>` elements you add dynamically. The code would look like the following:

```
$('#widgetContainer').on('submit', 'form.product', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  productList(formId);
});
```

The above code is using [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to handle the `submit` event for any `<form>` element with a class of "product". In the handler, we get the `id` attribute of the `<form>` element's parent.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/dgmuh53q/) is a fiddle for reference.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I did manage to make it work but this is much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, jQuery's `append()` parses the HTML-string by using `Element.innerHTML`.

As mentioned in [MDN's section *Security considerations* for `innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations):

> ... HTML specifies that a `<script>` tag inserted with `innerHTML` should not execute.

So instead of executing the code by appending a `<script>` tag, simply execute it:

```js
var template = /*without script tag*/;

$("#widgetContainer").append(template);

// Script tag's code
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() => {
  const product = document.querySelector("#productId_${index}")
  product.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formId = "productId_${index}";
    productList(formId);
  });
});
```

Or better, **use event delegation** as [76484's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76351604/13561410) shows. That way you wouldn't have to add individual listeners.